# Android - TextView Hyperlink para outra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Existe alguma maneira de formatar um TextView para que uma de suas palavras sejam um HyperLink para outra Activity do app?

No caso é uma espécie de Dicionário, onde na explicação da palavra pode ter outra palavra que também está cadastrada, e ao clicar na palavra iria direcionar para a Activity com a sua explicação.

Exemplo:
Mouse

"Dispositivo" de entrada dotado de um a três botões...

Dispositivo seria uma palavra clicável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só você utilizar uma `SpannableString` e usar o `onClick` da classe `ClickableSpan`. Nesse caso criei uma subclasse, para caso queira criar um link em mais de uma palavra. Ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Dispositivo de entrada dotado de um a três botões...");

    //aqui você coloca o índice da palavra que você quer, no caso 0 até 11
    ss.setSpan(new CustomClickableSpan(), 0, 11, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   textView.setText(ss);
   textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}

class CustomClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
    // aqui você abre a Activity que você quer
    // Intent....
   }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
       ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);//cor do texto 
       ds.setUnderlineText(false); //remove sublinhado
    }
}
}
```

Documentação: [ClickableSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html), [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso que estava procurando. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.